How to edit green spaces on Google Maps?
My city has many green spaces, including parks, gardens, playgrounds, meadows and nature reserves. On Google Maps, some are shown as green, but others are shown as grey urban area.
How can I edit Google Maps to record green spaces?
In the screenshot below, you can see 'Green End Road recreation ground' is shown as green space, but 'Bramblefields nature reserve' appears as urban grey. This makes it hard for map users to discover the nature reserve without zooming or clicking.


It appears it's not possible for Google Maps users to edit green spaces.
Other users have the same problem:

https://support.google.com/maps/thread/12995880/how-to-mark-our-public-park-to-show-as-green-in-google-maps?hl=en
https://support.google.com/maps/thread/16876201/how-can-i-add-a-city-park-on-google-maps-so-that-it-shows-up-in-green?hl=en
https://support.google.com/maps/thread/24922584/park-not-marked-as-green?hl=en

Hundreds more at https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asupport.google.com%2Fmaps+park+green
